# Default UIAccessibilityElement after screen change

Tags: ios, accessibility, uiaccessibility

Is there any way to decide which element gets focus first? I tried use the second parameter in the following method

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(
    UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification, 
    element
)
```

but with no success.

Comment: Are you sure that the `element` is an accessibility element? If so, could you post some more information about the problem so that we can help you. `UIAccessibilityPostNotification( ... );` works for me.

Comment: Also, if there is a screen change (major) instead of a layout change (minor) then you should post `UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification` instead.

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember exactly. I think the solution was of the kind where you just try all permutations and hope for the best... :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the `UIAccessibilityPostNotification` method is the [proper way](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/development/#notify-a-content-change) to get your purpose.

There are several types of change notifications but the two most commonly used are :

- **UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification** : notifies that a part of the page has changed with 2 possible incoming parameters *(a NSString or a UIObject)*.
  With a NSString, the notification behaves like a UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification with a VoiceOver vocalization.
  With a UIObject, focus is shifted to the user interface element.
  This notification is very similar to the UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification but should come as a result of dynamic content being deleted or added to the current view.
- **UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification** : notifies that the whole page has changed including nil or a UIObject as incoming parameters.
  With nil, the first accessible element in the page is focused.
  With a UIObject, focus is shifted to the specified element with a VoiceOver.
  This notification comes along with a vocalization including a sound like announcing a new page.

**Your problem may be the `element` type you specify** in your line of code apparently because it seems perfectly correct.